# Folder permissions on Web server

Tags: nginx, jenkins, php

I have Jenkins set up doing tests and other nice stuff for a college PHP project. What I would like to do is telling Jenkins (through a deploy job) to copy the source code folder to a Web folder I have running with nginx and php-fpm.

I’m really, really new to much of this technical knowledge, for instance, so I’m still trying to figure out how to set all this up. I have nginx and php-fpm running as **http** user/group configuration.

I’ve been reading about PHP-FPM pools, but I’m still curious as to how to set up the whole process.

Where do I set folder permissions for that Web folder so that I don’t have to use sudo or root everywhere? How do I reference it in nginx without user:group problems? Same as PHP? Can Jenkins simply run a `cp source/folder webserver/project` by adding it to the http group, or in fact, without using sudo at all? Yes, I know, a lot of questions, and a lot of doubts about permissions/security.

Thanks in advance!

PD: This is on a RackSpace Cloud Server running ArchLinux, nginx 1.0.10, PHP-FPM 5.3.8 and Jenkins 1.439.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming jenkins is run as a user different from `http`, the easiest way to achieve this would be to add that user to `http` group and ensure that the relevant webserver folder has `write` permission for `http` group. (drwxrwxr-x or similar).

Comment: That’s indeed what I had thought, and indeed what I had to do. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You should set the right file permissions using chmod: http://www.unixref.com/guides/chmodGuide.html

Comment: Something like: ´chmod -R 777 webserver/project´, and then on Jenkins I should do just like I had thought, a simple: ´cp source/folder webserver/project´?

Comment: I know, this is really old, but I just stumbled on this and I just can't say nothing on the suggestion of doing a `chmod -R 777`. Please **NEVER** do that! As pointed out in the answer above there are better and way more secure ways to that. `chmod -R 777` means that everyone can access all files under that parent folder.